# Hide Numeric Keyboard ONLY WHEN clicked outside any of the Edit Text

Tags: android, touch, android-softkeyboard

I have three different Edit Text with restriction of entering only numeric values, thus tapping on any one of the Edit Text opens NUMERIC KEYBOARD.

I tried to implement setOnFocusChangeListener for all Edit Text which ensures that when user tap anywhere outside any of the Edit Text hide the keyboard.

```
editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            hideKeyboard(v);
        }
    }
});

editText2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            hideKeyboard(v);
        }
    }
});

editText3.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            hideKeyboard(v);
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the implementation of 'hideKeyBoard'

```
public void hideKeyboard(View view) {
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
```

This works fine, however, when I change focus from one EditText to another EditText, keyboard hides. This behaviour might be frustrating for user.

How can I deal with it and avoid unnecessary hiding of keyboard.

**P.S** I need to ensure that keyboard is numeric not alphabetical in any case.

Comment: When the user tap other EditText, the previous EditText lose focus... then, hides the Keyboard. Maybe you can think in "if user focus on: RelativeLayout, LinearLayout, etc" hide the keyboard and not anywhere outside the EditText

Comment: @Mariano The way you suggested unfortunately shows up alphabetical keyboard (reason of my PS)

Comment: Can you post your exittext xml inside the layout? You can set the edittext to always be numerical.

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla Thank you very much, your way helped and its working. Sorry for not appreciating your help earlier. I was away from internet for couple of days.

Comment: Not a problem :) glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you MarianoZorrila for correcting me on my approach to the problem.
Here are the changes I performed to solve this problem.

1. Gave an Id to my Relative Layout

   ```
   <RelativeLayout
   ...
   ...
   android:id="@+id/parent">
   ```
2. Modifications to Java File

   ```
   View parent = findViewById(R.id.parent);
   parent.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
       @Override
       public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
           if(hasFocus){
               hideKeyboard(view);
           }
       }
   });
   ```